# how to provide service account details to terraform cloud variable? throws 'unexpected end of JSON input'

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-cloud

I'm trying to use terraform cloud with a gcp provider, a pretty basic use case.

The major issue is -- how do I provide the google provider as a variable to the cloud version of terraform? I've added the JSON variable and removed the `\n` as instructed, but it still throws `unexpected end of JSON input` when running `terraform apply`

There is no documentation mentioning terraform cloud in the google provider documentation or for the terraform documention on google pages.

I've been beyond the 10th page of google for various searches with no luck, I literally can't use terraform cloud with GCP for the most basic tasks and the lack of support around this issue is shocking.

Comment: Have you contacted [HashiCorp support](https://support.hashicorp.com/)? This sounds like something they would be best equipped to help with. (Stack Overflow is aimed more at programming questions than questions about using particular web applications.)

Comment: @MartinAtkins this isn't a support issue, their system is not malfunctioning, this is a tool usage issue which is exactly what stackoverflow is for.

Comment: While that might be true, since we can't see the JSON it's pretty hard to know what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was found on a few hashicorp forum posts -- for the GCP provider specifically the environment variable name must be set to `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` and it does not appear to work with other variable values for this specific provider, it also doesn't seem to be documented on the gcp provider page or on any terraform-cloud specific pages.

You also have to edit your json to remove all the whitespace so that you have everything on 1 line before copy-pasting it into terraform cloud. In my case, I was already doing that but others might not be aware.

Answer (score -1):

All the instructions to set up Terraform Cloud are documented [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#primary-authentication). In the  `Using Terraform Cloud` section:

> 1. Create an environment variable called GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS in your Terraform Cloud workspace.
> 2. Remove the newline characters from your JSON key file and then paste the credentials into the environment variable value field. You can use the tr command to strip newline characters. cat key.json | tr -s '\n' ' '

Comment: whilst that is one of the options documented in general for the GCP provider -- nowhere does it mention that for terraform cloud only the GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS varible is supported. Coming from local usage where all options documneted there works, it is not an assumption one can make.

Comment: If all the local options were supported as well, the instructions would be different but it's explicitly stated to create a variable called `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS`.